# How to add AttributeString to 'WriteElementString' element in C# XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to make a XML regarding to XSD. I generate a sample XML file and in that file its written an elemant as `<test tip="abc">2560602000</test>`

I am trying to generate this line by code in C# and my code is

```
    writer.WriteStartElement("test", null, "2560602000"); 
writer.WriteAttributeString("tip", "abc");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Above code is generating `<test: tip="abc" xmlns:test="2560602000" />`

And if I change my code to `writer.WriteAttributeString("tip", "abc");
 writer.WriteElementString("test", null, "");`

It is giving error.

My question is how can I generate a line as I explained above?

---

**SOLVED**

I used this solution and solved my problem

[Solution from question "*WriteStartElement with a tag name and string to indicate tag name*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435792/2037521):

```
xw.WriteStartElement("entry");
xw.WriteAttributeString("key", "RecordTotal");
xw.WriteString("10");
xw.WriteEndElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement test = new XElement("test", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("tip", "abc"),
                2560602000
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How will I use it with writer  element? I should write the line to my main xml

Comment: You need to add the element to your main xml.  You can convert element to a string using test.ToString() if necessary.  I don't know what you main xml looks like so I can't give better answer.