# Adding more values to a start element on XMLWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I'm kinda new to writing xml files using xmlwriter in C#. I'm trying to write one document with a few tags just like this, where there's more than one attribute inside one tag:

```
<FILE DATE="20220627" NAME="FILEINFO.20220627">
```

I've tried doing this but the compiler throws an exception warning that I can't create an element with a white space or "="

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("FILE DATE= " + CurrentDay + "NAME= FILEINFO." + CurrentDay);
```

Any idea on how I could make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLWriter: WriteStartElement with a tag name and string to indicate tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435735/xmlwriter-writestartelement-with-a-tag-name-and-string-to-indicate-tag-name)

Answer (score 0):

The element name in your sample is only `FILE`, `DATE` and `NAME` are attributes that you need to add separately:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("FILE");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("DATE", CurrentDay);
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("NAME", "FILEINFO." + CurrentDay);
// ...
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```